# Cordova facebook plugin empty content on share dialog

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, share, phonegap-facebook-plugin

I use this code to show Facebook share dialog

var post_id = fid.split('_');
var options = {
                method: "feed",
                link: 'http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=' + post_id[1] + '&id=' + post_id[0]
            };

```
        $cordovaFacebook.showDialog(options)
            .then(function(success) {
                console.log(success)
                alert('options');
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log(error)
            });
```

on iOS it's work ok, but on Android I get empty content
http://prntscr.com/8m9vm1

What can be the reason for it?

Answer (score 1):

Change the 'href' as 'link' in buildContent function in the file ConnectPlugin.java.
it works for me :)